# UrlDecodeException - Ajax - Struts2

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I need to take the information (year) from the HTML and based on that, retrieve the information from the database.
When I select the year from select, everything works, when the year is text an exception appears.

**URL:**

```
<s:url var="loaderURL"
   namespace="/myProject/myFolder"
   action="myAction"
   method="checkInformation">
</s:url>
```

**Select (works):**

```
<s:select id="year-select"
   data-url="%{#loaderURL}"
   name="years"
   list="items.years"
   listKey="value"
   listValue="label"/>
```

**div (doesn't work):**

```
<div class="divClass" data-url="%{#loaderURL}">
    <s:property value="items.year" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
    $("#year-select").each(function() {
        const url = $(this).attr('data-url');
        fetchInformation(url, $(this).val());
        $(this).change(function() {
            fetchInformation(url, $(this).val());
        });
    });

    $(".divClass").each(function() {
            const url = $(this).attr('data-url');
            fetchInformation(url, $(this).text());
    });
```

**Exception:**

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request.io] (default I/O-22) UT005090: 
Unexpected failure: io.undertow.util.UrlDecodeException: 
UT000072: Failed to decode url /myProject/myFolder/%%7B to charset UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a regular `div` so your loaderUrl is not rendered, try using an s:property in the div tag

```
<div class="divClass" data-url="<s:property value='#loaderURL' />">
    <s:property value="items.year" />
</div>
```